# Accesing the form data of an InlineModelAdmin from the parent Admin

Tags: python, django

I have a model admin for a CateringOrder model, which has a list of restaurants in a many-to-many table. These can be added and modified on an InlineModelAdmin that I've included.

I want to access the form fields on the inline form. I noticed that they can be accessed in form.data, but I feel like there must be an easier way.

Here is my code:

```
class CateringOrderRestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    notify = forms.BooleanField(label="Notify?", required=False)

    def save(self, _request, catering_order_restaurant, form, change):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        catering_order_restaurant.save()


class CateringOrderRestaurantInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = CateringOrderRestaurant
    form = CateringOrderRestaurantForm

    notify = forms.BooleanField(label="Notify?", required=False)
    fields = ["restaurant", "priority"]
    list_display = ("restaurant", "priority", "notify")
    raw_id_fields = ["restaurant"]
    extra = 1

class CateringOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
        "status",
        "super_hub",
        "delivery_location",
        "delivery_date",
        "delivery_preference",
        "non_vegetarians",
        "vegetarians",
        "vegans",
        "headcount",
        "rough_budget_per_head",
        "dietary_notes",
        "additional_requests",
        "delivery_notes",
    ]

    list_display = ('id', 'delivery_location', 'super_hub', 'status', 'delivery_date', 'headcount', 'budget')
    list_filter = ('status', 'delivery_date', )
    readonly_fields = ('status', 'headcount',)
    search_fields = ('delivery_location__company__name', 'delivery_preference',)
    raw_id_fields = ["delivery_location"]
    actions = ['cancel', 'finalize_orders']

    inlines = (
        CateringOrderRestaurantInline,
        CateringOrderItemInline
    )

    def save_model(self, _request, catering_order, form, change):
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        catering_order.save()

        if not change:
            email_inquiry(catering_order)
```

I need to access the value of the notify field in the overwritten save_model method on CateringOrderAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, if you override the save_related method the needed data will be passed in. Just used the wrong method...